# mmap error on ipad app with threading and core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I've had my project implemented with core data, however, whenever I tried to call save to a NSManagedObjectContext, the application goes on running for a long time and something like this appears:

```
Call(51871,0xb03e6000) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Call(51871,0xb03e6000) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Call(51871,0xb03e6000) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

My app runs 12 threads at the time this happens. Is this possibly because of a memory leak?

Comment: What does the Leaks instrument say?

Comment: It says that there is no leaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My app runs 12 threads at the time this happens. Is this possibly
>   because of a memory leak?

That you are running threads is irrelevant (except that it isn't•).   And, yes, this is most likely due to a memory leak or, at the least, abuse of memory.

It won't take very many 2,097,152 byte allocations for you to exhaust all available memory.   And it may not be leaks;  if you simply have a long running process that accretes lots of memory before cleaning up at the end, that can cause this behavior.

Without knowing more, it is very hard to say what is going on.  Certainly, setting a breakpoint as instructed and seeing where the failed allocation is occurring would be interesting.

---

• 12 threads is an awful lot in an iPhone app.  There is only one core (2 if on an iPad 2), memory I/O bandwidth isn't that great, and, thus, 12 threads competing for resources are very likely going to run a heck of lot slower than a couple of threads.

Furthermore, you shouldn't be spawning threads at all (outside of rare circumstances).  You should be using queues (GCD or NSOperationQueue) instead as they are far better integrated with the OS.